# mongoengine delete field raises ValidationError

Tags: python, mongoengine, validationerror

I'm using Flask with MongoEngine and as a test I tried to delete a collection from MongoEngine,but encountered an error,like it:

```
class Article(Document):
    slug = StringField(primary_key=True) # the article url
    title = StringField(required=True)
```

If i want add a new collection,i can:

```
Article(slug="article-1",title="hello mongoengine").save(force_insert=True)
```

Now i can visit it by open http://host:port/article-1, but when i want delete it,use:

```
Article.objects(slug="article-1").delete()
```

It will raises a error:

```
ValidationError: u'article-1' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string
```

and i test it with:

```
article_obj = Article.objects.with_id("article-1")
article_obj.delete()
```

It also can't work,so can someone tell me how to solve this question,
thanks!